# How to use local storage in quasar electron app ? #16733

Tags: vue.js, electron, local-storage, quasar-framework, quasar

I wanted to store my apps data in local storage but Im not sure how to achieve this in quasar electron app. Can someone guide me through how to use local storage for my data ?
Should I use reading and writing local files ? Should I use the local storage plugin ?
What should I use ?
Im pretty new to quasar I dont know how it works.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: This relevant to Electron, not Quasar